# how to schedule python script with parameters using crontab?

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script that needs 2 parameters when running, [url] & [keyword] . Once the file is done it outputs a .csv file with my results which are [position] , [url], [keyword] , [date] .

I'm trying to schedule this script to run once every day using crontab.

So, in other words, I'm trying to schedule the following to be run every day:

```sh
python3 script.py [url] [keyword]
```

I added the following in my crontab(I am trying to see if it works by running it every minute)

```
* * * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /path-to-my-script/rank.py
```

but nothing happens, I don't see my expected .csv files in the /path-to-my-script/ folder, and when I check the mail I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: file-name.csv: command not found
```

My python script looks like this:

```
import sys
import re
import random
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
import datetime
import csv


sitename = sys.argv[1]
keyword = "+".join(sys.argv[2:])

print("site: %s keyword: %s" % (sitename, keyword))

agent = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0',
         'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36',
         'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0',
         'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36',
         'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0']

parser = 'html.parser'

browser = RoboBrowser(history=False,
                      user_agent=random.choice(agent),
                      parser=parser)

browser.open('https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=' + keyword)

links = browser.find_all("div", {"class": "g"})

counter = 0



d=[]
for i in links:
    counter = counter + 1
    if sitename in str(i):
        url = i.find_all('a', href=True)
        position = "%d" % (counter)
        rank = "%s" % (url[0]['href'])
        now = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
        keyword = keyword
        d.append(keyword)
        d.append(position)
        d.append(rank)
        d.append(now)
        print(keyword, position, rank, now)



file =datetime.date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")+'-' +keyword + '.csv'
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Keyword' , 'Rank', 'URL' , 'Date'])
    writer.writerows(zip( d[0::4], d[1::4] , d[2::4], d[3::4]))
```

I want the following command to be run every day and store my .csv files in a specific folder

```sh
python3 script.py [url] [keyword]
```

Comment: It would be better to write a shell script that does the job of activating a virtual env (if you use one), adding input parameters to any python script and then put a cronjob on the shell script.

Comment: I'm not using a virtual environment. What my python script does is checks the URL and the keyword in Google and counts the position. So its like a day to day rank checker. I'm currently running it every day but I would like it to just run by itself.

Comment: * * * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /path-to-my-script/rank.py [url] [keyword] > /path-to-my-script/execution_logger.log 2>&1
 - Just add the url keyword at the end. log the stdin and stderr to see if the python script is executing normally.

Comment: Also, you might want to change your command if you want it run once a day. * * * * * * runs it every minute.

Comment: I added that, and an empty file execution_logger.log file showed up in my /path-to-my-script/ folder. When I check the mail I keep getting the following error 
/bin/sh: filename.csv: command not found.

Comment: You might also want to inspect your python script once. Is it running successfully without cron?

Comment: Yes. Its running perfectly if I just do $ python3 script.py arg arg in the terminal. Will get my csv file in the folder script.py is located

Comment: You should probably expect the output in your home directory,  which is where `cron` runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple example to demonstrate how you can schedule python scripts with args using a shell script and cronjob.

hello_world.py

```
import sys

def main():
    print(sys.argv[1])
    print(sys.argv[2])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

hello_world_scheduler.sh -- using such shell scripts have lots of added advantages that may come in handy in the future.

```
#! /bin/bash

cd /path_to_my_script
/usr/bin/python3 hello_world.py hello world! > execution_logger.log
```

Run

```
chmod +x hello_world_scheduler.sh ## to make the script executable
./hello_world_scheduler ## to run the shell script
cat execution_logger.log
```

The output should be

```
hello
world!
```

Just add the scheduler to cronjob -

```
* * * * * /path_to_script/hello_world_scheduler.sh
```

This should work

Comment: Thank you. This way it worked perfectly. I have a question, is the execution_logger.log just to check if my output is correct?

Comment: Yes, apart from the logs in your script, you may use this as it helps you capture all standard output (print statements, warnings) in a file.

Comment: Hey @skybunk, sorry for the confuision, but the .sh file works perfectly if i call it in the terminal. The thing that still doesnt work is when I schedule it in crontab. When checking the mails it keeps showing me this error: /bin/bash: myfilename.csv: command not found. In my python scrip im using writer to export my outputs in a csv file. Do I need to set my PATH or SHELL somehwere in m bash or crontab?

Comment: Could you add your python script in the question?

Comment: I added my python script.

Comment: upon first look, I think your program is unable to find the csv file.

Comment: try adding path_to_my_script + filename. And use os.path.exists(filename) to check if the csv file is there or not. also use 'w+' mode to create a new file - this will not work on existing files though. Also check out pandas library - it makes life really simple.

Comment: Hey skybunk, thanks for all your help. After a while, I figure it out why my cron job was not working. In your code, you added an extra *  . Thanks again for your help!